# Vertically shifted waveform

Tags: phase, waveform

I'm trying to make a vinyl rip sound clean as a digital copy in several steps and the first is *increasing high frequencies slightly and turning down the overall gain to prevent clipping*. Whoever wants to point out that it's easier to buy the digital copy, well they don't sell particular track digitally.
The audio looked [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjRrs.jpg) and after applying aforementioned manipulations it actually sounds better but I noticed that it looks [somewhat weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnukS.jpg) i.e. vertically asymmetrical, as if the left channel were dragged downwards and right one upwards, I doubt the master looked that way originally. Please explain what is the issue here and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical asymmetry's not a problem; likely just a product of the phase relationships between the superimposed sounds. There are ways of rectifying it (google phase rotator plugins) but it's no harm.

It's not DC offset - the entire waveform, including the silence at the beginning/end, would be shifted vertically one way or the other away from the infinity line if that were the case. (DC offset can be removed with a Hi-Pass filter set at 20Hz or somewhere thereabouts).

Sound on sound article with more info here: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/may13/articles/qanda-0513-1.htm

Might be worth re-ingesting it in any case, though, leaving yourself some more headroom; both waveforms look quite clipped!